# Finding the character table for Z_8

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

I am a bit confused about how to come up with the number of irreducible representations, as well to come up with the number of different conjugate classes.

Starting me out would be highly appreciated it.

After doing some reading, 8 = 1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+2^2

So this implies that there are 4 one dimensional representations and 1 two dimensional representation.

Comment: But this group is abelian, so all irreducible characters have dimension $1$, and there must be $8$ of them.

Comment: @DerekHolt see that's what I thought originally. I came up with conjugacy classes e,(xx),(xxx),(xxxx)...(xxxxxxxx), (xx)(xx)... I have more than 8

Comment: Well, the group is order 8, so there can't be more than 8. It's abelian so conjugacy does nothing, i.e. conj classes are singletons. So it has 8 1-dimensional representations. Z_8 is cyclic, let $g$ be a generator. You need to convince yourself that a character $\chi$ of Z_8 is uniquely determined by $\chi(g)$, and then work out what this value can be (note that $\chi(g)^8=1$).